# How to compare a mongocollection to a string?

Tags: java, mongodb

What can I use below instead of the getString method?

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = null;
LoginDto loginDto = gson.fromJson(body, LoginDto.class);
 if (collection.getString(loginDto.username) != null) {
        if (collection.getString(loginDto.username).equals(loginDto.password)) {
```

Comment: Always [read the documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.5/apidocs/mongodb-driver-sync/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html) first.  You probably want to create a Bson filter and pass it to a `find` method.

Comment: This question is a bit unclear to me. What are you trying to accomplish?